# Google BigQuery ML

Tags: google-bigquery

I am struggling to use BigQuery's ML features. Basically, I write the following query and the it fails with this message:

> Syntax error: Unexpected string literal 'finance-ml-jdb.FOREX.EURGBP'
>   at [17:3]

```
   CREATE MODEL `finance-ml-jdb:FOREX.EURGBP_Model`
   OPTIONS( model_type         = 'linear_reg',
            input_label_cols   = bidlow,
            ls_init_learn_rate = .15,
            l1_reg             = 1,
            max_iterations     = 5
           ) AS
   SELECT
     bidopen,
     bidhigh,
     bidlow,
     askopen,
     askclose,
     asklow,
     tickqty
   FROM
      'finance-ml-jdb.FOREX.EURGBP'
   Order By
      CAST(date AS DATETIME) DESC
```

I suspect I've got something wrong with the use of '' or `` when specifying finance-ml-jdb.FOREX.EURGBP but I'm not sure exactly what I need to do to fix it.

Any help would be much appreciated,

Thanks,

Josh

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax error: Unexpected string literal '93868086.ga\_sessions\_' at \[1:244\] - BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51143932/syntax-error-unexpected-string-literal-93868086-ga-sessions-at-1244-big)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you will fix

```
FROM 'finance-ml-jdb.FOREX.EURGBP'
```

to

```
FROM `finance-ml-jdb.FOREX.EURGBP`
```

your next issue will be below line

```
        input_label_cols   = bidlow,
```

It should be fixed to

```
        input_label_cols   = ['bidlow'],
```

And finally, you should remove below line,as it is not useful for CREATE MODEL and only can result with `Resource Exceeded ...` if you have relatively large data for training

```
   Order By CAST(date AS DATETIME) DESC
```

Comment: Thats really useful and clears up several errors. However, after running the new corrected query. I get the following error An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed.

Comment: Then this solved your question but now you have a different problem. May you create a new question specifying the details or providing an example of your actual query?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use back-ticks, not single quotes.

```
`finance-ml-jdb.FOREX.EURGBP`
```